# Azure Stream Analytics query to detect missing alive event for a specific deviceId

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-stream-analytics

I do not see a way to analyse a stream for the absence of a specific event with azure stream analytics query language.
The stream may contain DeviceAlive and BeaconDetected events containing a DeviceId and in case of BeaconDetected also a BeaconId. Now I want to generate an error event if the DeviceAlive event is missing.

How can I achieve this?
I tried to use reference data with all valid deviceIds. 
But I am not allowed to do a linq-wise "contains" query like this

```
SELECT * FROM
     inputStream
WHERE DeviceId IN (SELECT Id FROM DeviceReferenceData)
```

How can I do such a query. Is this possible by joining the inputStream with the DeviceReferenceData table?
I guess I just do not see the obvious.

The events e.g. are looking like this:

```
 {
    "EventType": "DeviceAlive",
    "DeviceId": "winiot-pi",
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-11-19T11:00:20.5594584+01:00"
 },
 {
    "EventType": "BeaconDetected",
    "BeaconId": "2",
    "DeviceId": "winiot-pi",
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-11-19T11:00:20.5594584+01:00"
 }
```

Doing a query like this, does not produce the expected result:

```
SELECT
    iothub.*,r.id as rerId
into output
FROM
    iothub TIMESTAMP BY EventEnqueuedUtcTime
Left OUTER Join devicesReference r on iothub.DeviceId = r.Id
```

This only returns a NULL referenceId for every DeviceAlive event. The output in csv:

```
eventenqueuedutctime;EventType;BeaconId;DeviceId;SignalStrength;rerid
19.11.2018 10:00:20;BeaconDetected;1;winiot-pi;-40;winiot-pi
19.11.2018 10:00:20;BeaconDetected;1;winiot-pi2;-80;winiot-pi2
19.11.2018 10:00:20;ReceiverDeviceAlive;winiot-pi;winiot-pi;;
19.11.2018 10:00:21;ReceiverDeviceAlive;winiot-pi2;winiot-pi2;;
19.11.2018 10:00:21;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi;-80;winiot-pi
19.11.2018 10:00:21;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi2;-40;winiot-pi2
19.11.2018 10:00:25;ReceiverDeviceAlive;winiot-pi;winiot-pi;;
19.11.2018 10:00:25;ReceiverDeviceAlive;winiot-pi2;winiot-pi2;;
19.11.2018 10:00:31;BeaconDetected;1;winiot-pi2;-40;winiot-pi2
19.11.2018 10:00:31;BeaconDetected;1;winiot-pi;-80;winiot-pi
19.11.2018 10:00:32;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi;-40;winiot-pi
19.11.2018 10:00:32;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi;-40;winiot-pi
19.11.2018 10:00:33;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi2;-80;winiot-pi2
19.11.2018 10:00:36;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi;-40;winiot-pi
19.11.2018 10:00:46;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi2;-80;winiot-pi2
19.11.2018 10:00:46;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi;-40;winiot-pi
19.11.2018 10:00:57;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi2;-80;winiot-pi2
19.11.2018 10:00:57;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi;-40;winiot-pi
19.11.2018 10:01:07;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi2;-80;winiot-pi2
19.11.2018 10:01:07;BeaconDetected;2;winiot-pi;-40;winiot-pi
19.11.2018 10:01:20;ReceiverDeviceAlive;winiot-pi2;winiot-pi2;;
19.11.2018 10:01:30;ReceiverDeviceAlive;winiot-pi2;winiot-pi2;;
```

But what I need is the information on every time window also if the window does not contain any events. We can break it down to that question I guess:
How to query and see also time windows that have none of the desired events.
Is that altogether possible?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good advice to talk to a colleague, even if he does not fully understand what you are talking about. ;-)
Here is the solution for generating an error event by detecting the absence of alive events in a 30 second window for a dedicated device with the help of a reference device table.
Those links helped me a lot understanding more of it:

[azure stream analytics query to detect missing alive event for a specific device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2014/12/09/how-to-query-for-all-events-and-no-event-scenarios/)

[how to find absence of signal in a stream analytics job](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2015/12/17/how-to-find-absence-of-signal-in-a-stream-analytics-job/)

```
WITH OneEvent AS /* generate one event per period, any event */
(
            SELECT 
                COUNT(*) As eventCount,
                System.Timestamp as EndOfWindow
            FROM iothub TIMESTAMP BY EventEnqueuedUtcTime
            GROUP BY TumblingWindow(s, 30)
),
AllReferenceDevices AS /* generate one event per deviceId per period */
(
            SELECT devicesReference.Id, OneEvent.EndOfWindow
            FROM OneEvent JOIN devicesReference
            ON OneEvent.EndOfWindow = OneEvent.EndOfWindow
),
/* Select only the devices where we cannot find an event for */
DeviceConnectivityErrorDetection AS
(
    SELECT 
        'DeviceConnectivityErrorDetected' AS EventType,
        AllReferenceDevices.Id as FromDeviceId,
        AllReferenceDevices.Id as ToDeviceId,
        AllReferenceDevices.EndOfWindow as EventEnqueuedUtcTime
    FROM 
        AllReferenceDevices 
      LEFT join  iothub  TIMESTAMP BY EventEnqueuedUtcTime
   ON DATEDIFF(s, iothub, AllReferenceDevices ) BETWEEN 0 and 30 
            AND iothub.DeviceId = AllReferenceDevices.Id
    WHERE iothub IS NULL
 ) 


SELECT  *
INTO ReceiverDeviceConnectivityErrorDetectedOutput
FROM DeviceConnectivityErrorDetection
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, maybe you could use [JOIN reference Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/reference-data-join-azure-stream-analytics) to find the deviceId which is missing in the reference data collection. Please try below sql:

```
SELECT
    jsoninput.*,r.id as rerId
into output
FROM
    jsoninput
Left OUTER Join jsonreference r on jsoninput.id = r.id
where r.id is null
```

Comment: I tested it and added some more information to the question.

Comment: I guess for detecting "nothing" I will need something like this:
[how-to-query-for-all-events-and-no-event-scenarios](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2014/12/09/how-to-query-for-all-events-and-no-event-scenarios/) and maybe this [how-to-find-absence-of-signal-in-a-stream-analytics-job](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2015/12/17/how-to-find-absence-of-signal-in-a-stream-analytics-job/)