# Azure Messaging services: detecting the absence of a message

Tags: azure, message-queue, event-driven-design

Within an Azure micro-services environment, implementing an event driven architecture, I have the challenge of acting upon a received event. I also have the counter challenge of detecting a duration with no events.

Has anyone identified a way in which the recipient can be notified after a period of no events?

I have considered things like Azure functions polling the dataset however this won't scale particularly well due to the volume of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Azure Stream Analytics, and Windowing to detect if a window, e.g. the last x minutes, did not contain any new events. See here for a similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53430421/1537195